# Excel seeks many text strings in a cell by a list and returns an equivalent value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, search, sorting

So, I have the problem that is search some strings in a cell by the list.
For example:

sheet 1:

```
    A                                     B     C
   ---                                   ---   ---
1 | Cash in deposit (Branch A t/t)
2 | Borrowed from Corp. A
3 | Interest payment
4 | Int.panalty pmt
5 | Prin. Pmt
6 | Salary Pmt on April
7 | Sales abroad
8 | Branch C t/t
9 | Transferred from Company AA
10| Mortgages to DD ltd
11| Sal. Pmt on May
```

And at B1 cell, I enter the formula like this:

```
=IF(COUNT(SEARCH({"branch","corp.","company"},A1))>0,"Precol.",IF(COUNT(SEARCH({"interest","int.","prin."},A1))>0,"lo.",IF(COUNT(SEARCH("sales",A1))>0,"Sa.",IF(COUNT(SEARCH({"sal.","Salary","wage","payroll"},A1))>0,"Se.","Others"))))
```

The formula is too long and too many parentheses, this is not good if I have a long list to sort.

So, could you help me to shorten or create another formula more effectively than it?

Comment: Why are you unhappy with your formula? It seems to work fine to me. Could you expand on what you're trying to do and where the above falls short?

Answer (score 0):

My old formula will be long if there has many arguments.

Finally, I used lookup function to solve my question, that is such below:

IFERROR(LOOKUP(2^5,SEARCH(keyword,A1),keystring),"others")

In which:
- keyword includes Branch, corp, company ... and sales
- keystring includes Precol., Lo., Se., Sa.

But i'm not still satisfied, I want to have other solutions besides them.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I've just seek a new solution like this: if I name the range for "branch, corp., company ... and sales" into keyword; the range for "Precol., Lo., Se., Sa." into keystring. My formula will be =IFERROR(INDEX(keystring,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(keyword,A1)),0)),"Others") and Ctrl-shift-enter. I will have the similar result.